# Render a view with some variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller `donations_controller`

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    donation = Donation.find_by_id(1).donation
    donation_percent = donation.to_f/50*100
  end
end
```

and a view `donations/_index.html.erb`

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width:<%=@donation_percent%>%;"></div>
</div>
<p>Donated: &euro;<%=@donation%></p>
```

When I try to render it inside any other view (e.g `static/index.html.erb` - my website homepage) it is rendered without the variables. Here is the code I use

```
...
<%=render partial: "donations/index", donation: @donation, donation_percent: @donation_percent%>
...
```

What should I do to render the variables as well? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have
`<%= yield %>`

In your layout?

Comment: Of course I have, but how can it help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put values from controller you want to access in views into instance variables, so:

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @donation = Donation.find_by_id(1).donation
    @donation_percent = @donation.to_f/50*100
  end
end
```

Next, your `index` view is almost right, you pass these instance variables into partial as locals (but forgot wrap them in locals hash):

```
...
<%=render partial: "donations/index", locals: {donation: @donation, donation_percent: @donation_percent} %>
...
```

But in partial you should call them as local variables

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width:<%= donation_percent %>%;"></div>
</div>
<p>Donated: &euro;<%= donation %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to access the @donation since it is not defined other than Donation#index action(assuming).

You have two options
 1) Either you put the code wherever you want to access the donation

```
@donation = Donation.find_by_id(1).donation
@donation_percent = @donation.to_f/50*100
```

2) Or declare the the template as partial instead of rendering the template render as partial and rename your file to '_index.html.haml'

render partial: 'donations/index', donation: @donation

Change the variable name from @donation to donation

Comment: I've done it and yet nothing's changed, even if I try to render in within any other view. I'll rewrite my question according to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually render the partial inside your layout. Put a `<%= yield %>` in the place where the partial should be and Rails will handle choosing and rendering the correct template for the current action.

As to your original question - to propertly render one template from another, use `render partial`, not `render template`.

Further instructions can be found in the official [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: I need it not within yield, I need it as a part of the layout.